# What do the various parameters in the statistic file in HCRF (Hidden- state Conditional Random Field) classifier stand for?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, crf

> I  have been working in a project where the data is being classified
>   using HCRF classifier however the various parameters: 
>   `(Label, True, Marked, Detect, Prec., Recall, F1)` 
>   in the statistic file generated in
>   the process is quite difficult to understand. 
>  The image to the snap of the file has
>   been attached.
>
> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wez69.png]

Comment: is This classifier  unsupervised??

Comment: i am sorry sir, i certainly have no idea about HCRF being supervised or not.

Comment: Can you post the code, or tell which platform you are using? is it matlab? R?

Comment: yes it is matlab we are using it with and it has no code. We have two files dataTest.csv and dataTrain.csv and we process the thing using the command >>testHCRF -t -T -d dataTrain.csv -l labelsTrain.csv -D dataTest.csv -L labelsTest.csv -m model.txt -f features.txt -r results.txt -c stats.txt -o bfgs -a hcrf<< and get files like model features results and stats generated. the snap of the stats has been linked with the question.